# Is my proof formal/rigorous enough?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

As a self-learner, I always have the problem of not knowing if my proofs are rigorous enough or presented such that they'd be satisfactory for an actual real analysis class.

Q: Let $a<b$ be real numbers and consider the set $T = \mathbb{Q} ∩[a, b]$. Show $\sup T=b.$

Pf: If $b \in \mathbb{Q}$, $\sup T = b$ because $b$ is an upper bound ($b \geq t, \forall t$) and $b \in T$. The case $b \in \mathbb{I}$, and therefore $b \notin T$, is more complicated. Regardless, $\sup T$ can only be less than, greater than, or equal to $b$. Let's rule out the former two:

For $\sup T < b$, this can't be the case because there is an infinite number of elements approaching $b$ and, therefore, there will always exist an upper bound, rational, larger than the prior. For example, in $S = \{r \in \mathbb{Q}: r^2 < 2\}$, $r$ approaches $\sqrt2$ but never reaches it; any attempt at a maximum is immediately succeeded.

For $\sup T >b$, this can't possibly be the case because T only includes elements up to, and below, b.

Therefore, $\sup T = b$.

Comment: I believe formulation "there is an infinite number of elements approaching $b$" should be sustituted with "in $T$ there is an infinite sequence of rational numbers approaching $b$ (for example sequence $c_n=\lfloor b\cdot 10^n \rfloor \cdot 10^{-n}$". As for your example with $r^2<2$, I believe "$r$ approaches $\sqrt{2}$" is not correct formulation for set. And example does not prove, only explains your idea. For $\sup T > b$ case you can consider number  $f=\frac{\lfloor d e \rfloor}{e}$, where $d=\frac{b+\sup T}{2}$, $e=\lfloor \frac{2}{\sup T - b}+1\rfloor$. $f$ makes contradiction

Comment: You can also find analogous to $f$ number for case $\sup T < b$. This number $g$ would be such rational number that is less than $b$ and greater than $\sup T < b$.

Comment: I’d say it’s much, much easier to argue that if $a\le\sup T=x\lt b$, then by density of the rationals there exists a rational $q$ in the nonempty interval $(x,b)$, and then $q\in T$ also, which is a contradiction to $q\gt\sup T$.

Comment: "*For $\sup T \lt b$*" $\;-\;$ Here you are basically restating the conclusion in different words, and giving an example, instead of actually proving it. If you know that $(*)$ any non-empty interval $(a,b)$ contains at least one rational (and thus infinitely many), then you could say that $\,(\sup T, b)\,$ will contain a rational strictly greater than $\,\sup T\,$, which contradicts the definition of $\,\sup T\,$. If you don't know or cannot use $(*)$ then you'll have to prove it (or an equivalent statement) from scratch.